# Как создать QML-плагин в Visual Studio с использованием расширения QtVsTools?

Tags: qt, visual-studio, qml

Чтобы создать плагин в QT с использованием файла PRO, просто укажите:

```
  CONFIG += plugin qmltypes
  QML_IMPORT_NAME=Geometry
  QML_IMPORT_VERSION=1
```

Но в Visual Studio такого нет, я не понимаю, как там создать плагин.

Comment: Вы можете создать плагин в pro файле, а затем [qmake -tp vc project.pro](https://forum.qt.io/topic/89885/qmake-to-generate-visual-studio-solution) и получите project.sln.

Comment: он таким образом генерирует очень много мусора и непонятных объектов. Такой проект в дальнейшем невозможно поддерживать. Необходимо именно из VS создать

Comment: Возможно, есть обходной путь - в версии до Qt 5.15 не было CONFIG +=  qmltypes. Все обходились qmlRegisterType. Но это работает только для C++ файлов. Нигде не могу найти, как зарегистрировать QML файл таким же способом

Comment: @MaksBuilder а зачем вам поддерживать сгенерированный sln, вы pro поддерживайте и после каждого изменения pro делайте новый sln, при этом из VS можно даже не выходить, VS предлагет перегрузить проект когда видит обновление